# "Email already taken" redirect_to login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model-view-controller

If the validation fails...

**user.rb**

```
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }
  has_secure_password
```

because "Email already taken" the user should be redirected to `sessions/new` to login otherwise the `users/new` page should refresh with the appropriate error message such as, "Password can't be blank".

**users_controller**

```
  if # How to make conditional work where if email is already taken do this...
    flash[:alert] = "EMAIL ALREADY TAKEN. LOG IN WITH EMAIL"
    render 'sessions/new'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

**User put email that already exists...**

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"teFpI/xcFe4Ngdtcj8+7DEj+3ipMBObjzBjs143ILQ/bpefsZSuWWh7cxKJJRXqmCAW+35/H9UPKB56SDdO+6A==", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"mon", "email"=>"testmonkey@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "subscribe"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('testmonkey@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 496ms (Views: 159.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
```

**user.rb**

```
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }
  has_secure_password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like this:

```
def create
  if User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email]).present?
    flash[:alert] = "EMAIL ALREADY TAKEN. LOG IN WITH EMAIL"
    render 'sessions/new'
  else
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      # handle successful save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you don't create a variable `@user`(because of `return`) the error message is not showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `find_by_email` returns something different to `nil` when looking for the email in the existing records:

```
if User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
  flash[:alert] = "EMAIL ALREADY TAKEN. LOG IN WITH EMAIL"
  render 'sessions/new'
else
  render 'new'
end
```

Or if you want to be more specific, you can use `ActiveRecord#exists?`:

```
if User.exists?(email: params[:user][:email])
  flash[:alert] = "EMAIL ALREADY TAKEN. LOG IN WITH EMAIL"
  render 'sessions/new'
else
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Look carefully at your first example, you just checks if params contains value and show the message that email already taken, is it wrong?